# How to properly segue between view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I've run into this problem while trying in objective-c and now Swift. I create a view controller (vc1), embed it with a navigation controller and then finally create a new view controller (vc2). Then, I put a button on vc1, and control drag it to vc2. I run the app and everything is fine and dandy, clicking on the button will push the new view controller onto the stack and pressing the back button will take me back. However, once I proceed to add new buttons and text fields to vc2, the app will crash once I press my original button on vc1, citing the first line of the app delegate file as the breakpoint. I've tried many things, namely trying to code the segue using the self.performSegueWithIdentifier method but it does not work. I am using Xcode 6.

storyboard.swift (file for vc1):

```
import UIKit

class storyboard: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var titleLabel : UILabel
    @IBOutlet var orLabel : UILabel

    @IBAction func weightedAverageButtonPressed(sender : AnyObject) {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("weightedAverage1", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func whatINeedButtonPressed(sender : AnyObject) {
    }
}
```

weightedAverage.swift (vc2)(I've commented everything out to get rid of the crash, but no luck):

```
import UIKit

class weightedAverage: UIViewController {

 /*   @IBOutlet var weightAverageTitleLabel : UILabel
    @IBOutlet var percentagetoCalcLabel : UILabel
    @IBOutlet var percentageLabel : UILabel
    @IBOutlet var percentageInput : UITextField

    @IBAction func continueButton(sender : AnyObject)
    {

     //var percent = percentageInput.text

    // percentageLabel.text = percent

    }*/

}
```

appdelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

        return true
    }
}
```

Here is what the debug output says (when I've commented out my IBAction method):

2014-06-19 12:29:12.471 gradeCalc[13217:580024] -[_TtC9gradeCalc10storyboard weightedAverageButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bb0ad30
(lldb)

It also highlights the line of app delegate beginning in "class AppDelegate...."

When I uncomment the method which contains the performSegue... method ALL the output log says
"(lldb)" and it still highlights the line of app delegate

Comment: so....you have a view controller called `storyboard`?

Comment: yes, the initial view controller is called storyboard

Comment: To debug your crash, set an **exception breakpoint**, see how to do so here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: Once you've done that, you can paste the exception into your question and we can better help you.

Comment: ^I have edited the post to include the debug output, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the manual IBAction code for the button and just using the segue made on the Storyboard? It may be trying to segue twice simultaneously if you both used the Storyboard and the Class file to do it.

Edit: All the code in my working example for the two view controllers

First View Controller:

```
class OneViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var label1: UILabel

@IBOutlet var label2: UILabel

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Second View Controller:

```
class TwoViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var upperlabel: UILabel
@IBOutlet var lowerlabel: UILabel
@IBOutlet var textbox: UITextField
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    var percent = textbox.text
    lowerlabel.text = percent
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

Can't add an image due to NDA, but Storyboard is just NavigationController>VC1>VC2, with two labels in each VC, a text box in VC2, and a button in each. Only the second button has an action in its VC class.

Comment: Is the Segue's identifier named: weightedAverage1 in the storyboard?

Comment: If it's capitalized the same way and the view controller's class is set as storyboard in the storyboard, I can't think of anything else it would be. Sorry couldn't be of more help.

Comment: So I recreated your project and did get the same error setting it up your way. I don't know why, but doing it in this order led to no errors: make both views and navigation controller, then add all buttons and labels, then connect button on vc1 to segue to vc2 (on storyboard, no code), then change each view's class to your custom ones, then add outlets for labels/text boxes. So I'd suggest try remaking the views, add elements first and make sure it runs, connect them, make sure it runs, and do that step by step

Comment: presuming this works, am I going to have to make every single view I would want in my app before I connect all of them?

Comment: You could try just resetting the default class on the two views in the storyboard and then remaking the button to segue between them. You should still be able to add to the views later on, and this hopefully won't affect every one you make. Xcode 6 is hardly reliable though

Comment: its working! hopefully I can keep this up haha, thanks for all your help